# Can't show() QWindow when it was hidden with cmd + h on MacOS

Tags: macos, qt, qwindow

I have an issue that I cannot raise my app Window when it got hidden with MacOS shortcut. It work correctly in all other cases.

In my app i have 1 main qWindow called
`QWindow* mMainWindow;`
and following code added to tray button

```
    mMenu->addAction(createAction("Show", [=] {
        if (mMainWindow) {
            mMainWindow->show();
            mMainWindow->raise();
            mMainWindow->requestActivate();
        }
```

When I just use qt `mMainWindow->hide()` and then raise it back, `mMainWindow` works fine. Method `mMainWindow->isActive()` return correct `true` state when app is active and `false` when it is hidden.

But when I hide app using build-in in mac "cmd + h", `mMainWindow->isActive()` return `true` regardless if app app is hidden or not. Calling my action item does nothing, `mMainWindow` stay all the time hidden.

Is there any solution to fix this issue? I have seen people recommend using `QWidget` instead of `QWindow` and calling `widget->activateWindow()` but it is not solution i can use in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that if you call `hide()` before calling `show()`, `show()` will behaving correctly.

Workaround to this problem is following

```
mMenu->addAction(createAction("Show", [=] {
        if (mMainWindow) {
            mMainWindow->hide();
            mMainWindow->show();
            mMainWindow->raise();
            mMainWindow->requestActivate();
        }
    }));
```

there may be issue that when app is already on focus, and you click `Show` it will, hide and show again, but it is acceptable problem in my case.

Comment: Instead of hiding first (which could definitely result in window flickering on some platforms), have you tried other `show...` functions?

Comment: from qt doc for show() `This is equivalent to calling showFullScreen(), showMaximized(), or showNormal(), depending on the platform's default behavior for the window type and flags.` So it is same thing but with adding a flag with type of window. Yes i have tried manipulating flags. The issue is that `QWindow` "think" it is already active so it does nothing. Clearly some kind of qt bug.